# Can we merge the 'dev' and 'devices' tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I was re-tagging a question about developing applications when I noticed there was a [dev](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/dev) tag.  To me, both [dev](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/dev) and [devices](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/devices) (or maybe [development](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/development))  cover exactly the same thing.

Can we merge the tags or make [dev](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/dev) a synonym of [development](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/development)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No. **Trash [dev](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/dev) instead**. It seems to be used as an abbreviation for two unrelated subjects:

- devices (about 10)
- development (about 5)

So, let's just trash the [dev](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/dev) tag and retag the maybe even four real development questions. The use of dev for devices does not make sense to me. I do understand new users seeing `/dev/sda` and thinking 'dev' would be a nice tag...

Comment: Good points.  I didn't look at what questions were tagged with it.

Comment: @iSeth Okay, so how do we get this done? Accepting an answer doesn't make the system do what we want, unfortunately.

Comment: Yeah, I know.  That's why I wanted more attention... I'll try to get a hold of a mod in chat.

Comment: I see this has been done. Thanks to all involved.

Comment: @EliahKagan It's not completely done.  It still needs votes to become active.

Answer (score -1):

Jorge Castro has added [dev](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/dev) as a synonym of [development](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/development).  Users with a score of five in the [development](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/development) tag can vote for it [here](https://askubuntu.com/tags/development/synonyms)

While this isn't the answer everyone would like, (seeing gertvdijk's answer has 15 upvotes), but nothing else has been done about it so I think this is the best solution at the moment.

Comment: @gertvdijk I have no power over that....